# How do I host a Windows Terminal (to run Windows applications and be accessed by users via a standard MS Remote Desktop client) on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, windows, rdp, windows-terminal-services, wine

How do I host a Windows Terminal (to run Windows applications and be accessed by users via a standard MS Remote Desktop client) on a Linux server? I've heard there are some alternatives to Microsoft server software for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

LTSP is the Linux Terminal Server Project

RDP can only be used with windows servers hosting the terminal session, so you could bring up a windows VM on top of Linux, if RDP is really essential for you.

Otherwise, there are options, like VNC, X-forwarding, SPICE, NX etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative to Windows Terminal Services, assuming you actually want to run Windows applications, is Citrix. Remote screen software, such as VNC, etc., are no substitute for Terminal Services, which provides a separate environment for each user session.